# Finding a set $E$, $m(E)=0$, such that $m(f(E))>0$ where f is a continuous but not absolutely continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

"Suppose f is a continuous, but not absolutely continuous, function from [a,b] to $\mathbb{R}$, then find a set $E$ with Lebesgue measure $m(E)=0$ such that $m(f(E))>0$"
I'm having trouble answering this question, especially with the last step of my tentative proof. My reasoning went like this:

I've started by negating the AC hypothesis so: $\exists\epsilon>0$ such that $\forall\delta>0$ there exists disjoint intervals $\ (a_k,b_k)$ such that $\sum^n_{k=1}|b_k -a_k|< \delta$ and $\sum^n_{k=1}|f(b_k) -f(a_k)|> \epsilon$

Supposing this first step is correct, then I considered a sequence $\delta_n=1/n$ and a corresponding set of disjoint intervals $I_n$ such that$\sum^n_{k=1}|b_k,_n -a_k,_n|< \delta_n$ for every $(a_k,_n , b_k,_n)\in I_n$ with the added condition that $I_{n+1} \subset I_n$, and I do this by taking smaller intervals contained in the intervals of $I_n$ that satisfy $\sum^n_{k=1}|b_k,_{n+1} -a_k,_{n+1}|< \delta_{n+1}$ for every $(a_k,_{n+1} , b_k,_{n+1})\in I_{n+1}$. Now I take $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n = E$ and I have that $m(E)=0$

(Edited after comment) Since $m(f(I_n))>\sum^n_{k=1}|f(b_k,_n) -f(a_k,_n)|> \epsilon$ for $(a_k,_n , b_k,_n)\in I_n$, and since f is continuous I can use the intermediate value theorem, so $m(f(E))$ is at least $\epsilon$.

(PreEdit)Am I on the right track or is my reasoning completely wrong? I also didn't use the continuity hypothesis, and it feels like I had to but I don't know how.

Comment: Welcome. I think your negation is incorrect and I think $I_{n+1}\subseteq I_n$ requires justification

Comment: The intermediate value theorem will show that $|f(b)-f(a)|>\epsilon$ implies $m(f(b,a))>\epsilon$

Comment: @FShrike Thank you for the tips, I think I spotted the mistake in the negation. Is it necessary to prove that $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$ or is the fact that $\delta_n\to 0$ and that intervals that satisfy the negation exist $\forall\delta_n$ enough to prove that $m(E)=0$ and that E is the set I'm looking for?

Comment: I don't think you really mean $I_{n+1}\subseteq I_n$. I think you mean: $$\bigcup_{k=1}^{m_{n+1}}(a_{k,n+1},b_{k,n+1})\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{m_n}(a_{k,n},b_{k,n})$$You also should keep track of the $m_n$. It is wrong to write $I_n$ as the set of intervals with $\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{n}}(a_{k,\color{blue}{n}}),b_{k,\color{blue}{n}})<\delta$ since you cannot guarantee the exact number of intervals necessary (the red $n$) in terms of the $n$th step (blue $n$)

Comment: Guaranteeing that inclusion is not obvious to me. It may be possible, but surely requires justification. Oh, and proving that $f(E)$ is measurable also seems like a subtle point of this exercise. At first glance this result looks very strong, providing an equivalent definition of absolute continuity

Comment: You're right, i didn't mean $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$, I got lost in the notation. I didn't even think about the measurability of $f(E)$ I wrongly assumed it would be measurable under continuous mapping. I'll have to work on this more